# Foreign Key with argument None : Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So, I was going through a code base and found this :

`user_id_column = Column('user_id', None, ForeignKey('people.people_id'))`

I can clearly understand that this is a foreign key column and referencing `people_id` column from `people` schema.

Just wanted to know what is the purpose of `None` ?
The type of data in people_id column is Integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is the type. From [the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.type_):

> If the type is None or is omitted, it will first default to the
> special type NullType. If and when this Column is made to refer to
> another column using ForeignKey and/or ForeignKeyConstraint, the type
> of the remote-referenced column will be copied to this column as well,
> at the moment that the foreign key is resolved against that remote
> Column object.

So setting the type to None means it uses the type of the foreign key.